# Why HotModuleReplacementPlugin uses Hard-Reload instead of Hot-Reload?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-hmr

Why the page is hard-reloading once I change the code? or why it didn't use the hot-reload instead of hard-reload? Is anything wrong with the HotModuleReplacementPlugin?

```
let serverConfig = {
  watchOptions:{
    aggregateTimeout: 300, //delay
    poll: 1000, // Poling interval
  },
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  compress: true,
  disableHostCheck: true,
  staticOptions: {
  },
  stats: { colors: true },
  contentBase: '../build/',
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  headers: {
    'X-Custom-Header': 'yes'
  },
  proxy: {
    '/**': {
      target: '/index.html',
      secure: false,
      bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
        if (req.path=='/config') {
          return res.json(_config.runtime)
        }
        return '/'
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear as your english level is low. Please try to rephrase your question, maybe with the help of someone more skilled in english.

Comment: Try using this plugin - https://github.com/shepherdwind/css-hot-loader.